# Why does this DynamicMethod (ldarg.1, newobj, ret) trigger a VerificationException?

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit, dynamicmethod, verificationexception

I have this method which wraps a constructor in a dynamic factory method:

```
static Func<TArg1, TResult> ToFactoryMethod<TArg1, TResult>(this ConstructorInfo ctor)
    where TResult : class
{
    var factoryMethod = new DynamicMethod(
         name:           string.Format("_{0:N}", Guid.NewGuid()),
         returnType:     typeof(TResult), 
         parameterTypes: new Type[] { typeof(TArg1) });

    ILGenerator il = factoryMethod.GetILGenerator();
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, ctor);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    return (Func<TArg1, TResult>)
         factoryMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<TArg1, TResult>));
}
```

However, the following code throws a `VerificationException` on the `.Invoke(…)`:

```
ConstructorInfo ctor = typeof(Uri).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(string) });
Func<string, Uri> uriFactory = ctor.ToFactoryMethod<string, Uri>();
Uri uri = uriFactory.Invoke("http://www.example.com");
```

The exception isn't thrown if I replace `ldarg.1`; `newobj <ctor>` with `ldnull`, so the problem must be caused by these two IL instructions. Further experiments suggest that the error lies with `ldarg.1`. (I've replaced this with a `ldstr <string>` for the specific example above.)

Does anyone see what's wrong with these IL instructions?

Comment: Your dynamic method seems to only have one parameter, and is static. Why are you using `Ldarg_1` instead of `Ldarg_0`? Since there is no "this" parameter (which usually is the 0 arg), you should use Ldarg_0.

Comment: I'm asking that myself, now. Silly me, I guess I assumed that the argument at index 0 were always reserved for the `this` object reference, even with static methods. Which is not the case, of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This method is static, so it doesn't have a `this` parameter as `arg0`. Changing `il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);` by `il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);` worked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the obvious! I was looking for some incredibly complicated error cause, but not for this... :-O